# Open a file in the browser from Silverlight

Tags: file, browser, silverlight-4.0

I have a Button (or a hyperlinkbutton) in Silverlight. I want to open a file on a server share when this butto in clicked. With other words I want a new Browser Tab or Window to open showing the requested file, just like I enter the URL in the browsers addressbar:

```
file://C:\myfile.txt
```

I tried in the OnClick Method the following:

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(@"file://C:\myfile.txt"),"_blank");
```

it throws an Exception (Access denied).
When I do the same with an http: page it works:

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(@"http://www.somedomain.com"),"_blank");
```

How can I achive the same with a file. Security can not be an issue, I have full access to that file. And please don't tell me that this is not possible... would mean we have to go back to PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox does not allow external URLs to link to a local resource anymore :(

Comment: The problem occurs in IE 7 AND Filerfox 3.6, I think it's a Silverlight issue. In Firefox 3.6 AND IE 7 I can view files by entering the local URL manually.

Comment: It seems to be a restriction of browsers in general, not only Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight runs on the client side and in by default in LOW trusted mode which dont allow application to access local file system. 
For the purpose, u can try giving full trust to the silverlight application.